# Does this requestAnimationFrame polyfill produce a timestamp aswell?

Tags: javascript

```
(function() {
var lastTime = 0;
var vendors = ['webkit', 'moz'];
for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
    window.cancelAnimationFrame =
      window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
}

if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
    window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
        var currTime = new Date().getTime();
        var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
        var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); },
          timeToCall);
        lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
        return id;
    };

if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
    window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
        clearTimeout(id);
    };
}());
```

As taken from https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671.
Within the first if statement it tests wether `requestAnimationFrame` exists as a window property. Within this if statement it creates the timeout needed to compensate, but does it also create a timestamp to be passed into the invoked function? What does the `element` argument do? I think I need someone to help me understand what happens here.

Here is a usecase to show what timestamp I am referring to:

```
var id = null,
start_time = null,
time_passed = null;

function loop( timestamp ){

   if( !start_time ) start_time = timestamp;

   time_passed = timestamp - start_time;

   if( time_passed < 1000 ){
        id = requestAnimationFrame( loop );
   }

}

id = requestAnimationFrame( loop );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop just tests the existence of `window.requestAnimationFrame` and `window.cancelAnimationFrame` by checking if vendor prefixed variations exist in the `window-object`.

The `element` parameter has been deprecated as seen in http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

> <strike>You’ll also notice the second parameter to requestAnimFrame: the
>   element that visually bounds the entire animation. For canvas and
>   WebGL, this will be the actual  element. For DOM stuff, you
>   can leave it off or define it for a slightly more optimized
>   experience.</strike> **It’s since been removed from the spec (and WebKit’s
>   implementation)**

It passes the current timestamp to the callback function:

```
var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); },
      timeToCall);
```

in which `currTime + timeToCall` is the moment the function was called. You can then use it, like you do in your example, in the animation function as the first parameter:

```
function loop(time){
  //time === current time
}
```

Comment: I referred  to the if statement as a loop which was wrong and creates confusion. Sorry for that. I know what the for loop does. I can also tell that the if statement then checks wether the property now exists. The element parameter is indeed depricated. Can you answer my main question aswell?

Comment: @Puddingboy answered the main question too (sorry, missed that. Though it stemmed from the confusion with the loop).